# Send DML commands from text files to PostgreSQL

Tags: bash

I have a folder with `*.sql` files. Each file is a multiline SQL command which I need to execute on PostgreSQL.

Here is my code:

```
DATA_DIR=db
SCHEMA=$DATA_DIR/schema

echo ================ Parameters:
echo SCHEMA=$SCHEMA

with_postgresql () {
    sudo docker exec postgresql sudo -u postgres psql -c
}

with_psql () {
    {
        while read LINE; do
            echo "$LINE"
        done
    } | with_postgresql
}


echo ================ Creating tables.
while read LINE; do
    echo Creating table: $LINE
    cat $SCHEMA/TABLE/$LINE.sql
done < $SCHEMA/meta/table_order | with_psql
```

When I run my script I get the message:

> ================ Creating tables. 
>   /usr/lib/postgresql/10/bin/psql: option requires an argument -- 'c'

It looks like `with_postgresql()` function don't pass the content of the file to `psql` command after `-c` key. How can I do it ?

Comment: Why don't you just use `psql -f $SCHEMA/TABLE/$LINE.sql` to execute the script?

Comment: I have *.sql files outside the docker container and cannot map them into docker volume.